# How to solve Invalid property value in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have introduced two new fields inside Alfresco using Model manager, those fields are List of values. After I run the application, and try to edit a file that contains those fields I get this:

[image]

The reason is not familiar to me, because this is not my first time that I create new fields, and before everything was ok.

If I add some values to be saved, then it is ok. I suppose that there is a connection with a database, but I am not sure.

This is the code:

```
               <field id="adadoc:regions" set='regionsAndCountries'>
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/select-many-regions.ftl">
                        <control-param name="mode">and</control-param>
                        <control-param name="style">width:325px</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>

                <field id="adadoc:countries" set='regionsAndCountries' >
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/select-many-countries.ftl">
                        <control-param name="mode">and</control-param>
                        <control-param name="style">width:325px</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: How you are getting values of Dropdown? From code it look like that values are coming through come api

Comment: you should also share the constraint definition in the model for `documentValuList` and `regions` to understand your issue.